# in Python how do call functions in __init__.py in a class defined in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python package

```
- my_package
  - __init__.py
       # inside
       def getSingleton()  # gets an instance of an object in the package
  - AClass.py
       # inside
       class AClass:
           ...
           def instanceMathod(self,arg):
              singleton = (parent package).getSingleton()
```

I want to use the module "static" functions from within class instances from the module ie: reference the parent module from a contained class instance?  Can one do this? Is there a better way?  Much works well as the singleton will be destroyed when the containing module is destroyed when all importing modules have been destroyed. I'm using python3

Comment: `from my_package import getSingleton`?

Comment: When do you expect the modules to be destroyed?

Comment: When they or the "connected component" they are are part of (everything that imports them) is no longer referenced, or if not then when the interpreter "main" exits

Comment: Anyway practically I solved it by setting the singleton as an attribute/property of the object instances that need it. (like java inner classes) - the though was the "package" ie: the folder with the __init__.py could be referenced like a "class"

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def instanceMethod(self,arg):
    from . import getSingleton
    singleton = getSingleton()
```

Here we are deferring the import until the method is called, rather than importing at global scope, in case `mypackage.__init__` is also importing `AClass`

Comment: interesting is this executed every time the method is called or is it "compiled out" to be called only once per load?